# How does combat work with weapons with two types of damage, in Two worlds?

Tags: two-worlds

In Two worlds some weapons give two types of damage, say [piercing and slashing](http://twoworlds.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarves%27_Downfall), how does this work out in combat? If I attack a creature "sensitive" to both types, does it get both, summed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of piercing and slashing damage, there is bludgeoning damage. These are just added damage that work only on specific characters, for example a skeleton cannot be affected by piercing and slashing damage, but it can be affected by bludgeoning damage.

Basically, different weapons work better for different enemies.

Comment: But if an enemy can be affected by two types of damage, does it get damage with both types at the same time?

Comment: @Joril Indeed it does, so pick your weapons wisely on the right enemy and you'll do a lot of damage.

Comment: As  a side note, as best I can tell, if you are wielding two weapons, each does their respective damage on their strike completion.